# Problemas con Query GX16

Tags: genexus

tengo dos consultas sobre el objeto query.

La primera es si hay posibilidad de al momento de de seleccionar un dato de la consulta pueda abrir un popup llamando a otro objeto.

La otra es  como sacar eso de la columna, quiero que solo me muestre el dato.

Muchas gracias.
[image: Print]

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Hola amigo, Bienvenido al Sitio, He verificado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask], Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], He visto que has agregado Imágenes, es preferible que tus ejemplos sean en texto y facilites el uso del mismo, También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El primer punto se puede resolver programando el evento ItemClick. Ver la documentación en https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?19570,ItemClick+Event

El segundo punto depende de cómo tengas configurada la propiedad Axis para ese quey element. Deberías configurarle Column según lo documentado acá
https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?47159,Axis+property+in+Query+Element,